# How to get "ajax" table from dynamic data with ("jQuery")

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a vieu that contion 4 combobox connect

we choose a 'metier' the list of 'tache' is displayed we choose a 'tache' the list of 'tarification' appears and by choosing a' tarification' list of 'technicien' who have this 'tarification' is displayed

I would like to change my view when I choose a 'tache' a table that contains the list of 'technicien' and the ' tarification' from table "tarificationtache" of each technicien displayed

iterventioncontroller

```
public function create()

{
$client = client::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
$metiers = metier::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
$technicien = Technicien::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
$tarifications = tarificationtache::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

return view('intervention.create')->with('technicien', $technicien)- 
>with('client',$client)- 
>with('metiers',$metiers)->with('tarifications',$tarifications);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(InterventionRequest $request)
{
$intervention = new Intervention();
$intervention ->date_intervention =$request->input('date_intervention');
$intervention ->description =$request->input('description');
$intervention ->duree_prevu =$request->input('duree_prevu');
 if($request->has('statut')){
$intervention->statut = $request->input('statut');
}else{
       $intervention->statut = 0;
}

$intervention ->technicien_id = $request->input('technicien_id');
$intervention ->client_id = $request->input('client_id');
$intervention ->tarification_id = $request->tarification_id;
$intervention->save();
return redirect('intervention');
}
```

create.blade.php

```
 @extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts/master')

@section('content')
<!--  jQuery -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">


var getTachesByMetierUrl = "{{url('/tachesbymetier')}}";
var getAdresseByClientUrl = "{{url('/adressebyclient')}}";
var getTarificationsByTacheUrl = "{{url('/tarificationsbytache')}}";
var getTechniciensByTarificationtacheUrl = " 
{{url('/techniciensbytarificationtache')}}";


//console.log(getMetiersByTechnicienUrl,getTachesByMetierUrl,  
getTarificationsByTacheUrl);


function getAdresseByClient(val) {
    if(val.length>0) {
        var client_id = val;
        $.get(getAdresseByClientUrl+'/'+client_id,function(res) {
            var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
            $.each(res.adresses,function(index,item) {
                html+='<option 
  value="'+item.id+'">'+item.code_postal+'</option>';
            });
            $('#adresses').html(html);

        });
    }
}


function getTachesByMetier(val) {
    if(val.length>0) {
        var metier_id = val;
        $.get(getTachesByMetierUrl+'/'+metier_id,function(res) {
            var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
            $.each(res.taches,function(index,item) {
                html+='<option 
value="'+item.id+'">'+item.libelle_tache+'</option>';
            });
            $('#taches').html(html);

        });
    }
}
function getTarificationsByTache(val) {

    if(val.length>0) {
        var tache_id = val;
        $.get(getTarificationsByTacheUrl+'/'+tache_id,function(res) {
            var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
            $.each(res.tarifications,function(index,item) {
                html+='<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.tarif+'</option>';
            });
            $('#tarifications').html(html);

        });
    }
}

function getTechniciensByTarificationtache(val) {
    if(val.length>0) {
        var tarificationtache_id = val;
  $.get(getTechniciensByTarificationtacheUrl+'/'+tarificationtache_id, 
  function(res) {
            var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
            $.each(res.techniciens,function(index,item) {
                html+='<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.id+'</option>';
            });
            $('#techniciens').html(html);

        });
    }
 }


</script>



@if(count($errors))
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
            <li>{{$message}}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
<div class="container">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="col-md-10">
    <h1>Ajout Intervention</h1>
    <form action=" {{url ('intervention')  }}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="client">Client</label>
            <select onchange="getAdresseByClient(this.value)" 
 name="client_id" id="client" 
class="form-control">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                @foreach($client as $t)
                    <option value="{{$t->id }}">
                        {{$t->user->nom}}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">date intervention</label>

            <input class="form-control" type="date" id="example-date-input" 
 name="date_intervention" value="{{old('date_intervention')}}">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">description</label>
            <input type="text"  name ="description" class="form- 
control"value=" 
{{old('description')}}">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">duree_prevu</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local"  name 
="duree_prevu" value=" 
{{old('duree_prevu')}}">
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Metier: </label>
            <select onchange="getTachesByMetier(this.value)" style="width: 
200px" 
class="productm form-control" id="metiers">
           <option value="">-Select-</option>
                @foreach($metiers as $t)
                    <option value="{{$t->id }}">
                        {{$t->libelle_metier}}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>tache: </label>
            <select onchange="getTarificationsByTache(this.value)" 
style="width: 200px" 
class="productname form-control" name="tache" id="taches">
            <option value="">-Select-</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>tarification: </label>
            <select onchange="getTechniciensByTarificationtache(this.value)" 
style="width: 
200px" class="productname form-control" name="tarificationtache_id" 
id="tarifications">
            <option value="">-Select-</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>technicien: </label>
                    <select style="width: 200px" class="productname form- 
control" 
name="technicien_id" id="techniciens">
                        <option value="">-Select-</option>
                    </select>
                </div>



</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap- 
datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"> 
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-         
datepicker.js"></script>
@endsection
```

model intervention

```
class Intervention extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [ ];
protected $guarded = [];

public function avisintervention()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AvisIntervention::class);
}

public function technicien()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(technicien::class);

}

public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);

}
 public function tarificationtache()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Tarificationtache','tarification_id');
```

}

model tarificationtache

```
public function tache()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tache::class);
}


public function techniciens()
{
    return $this- 
 >belongsToMany('App\technicien','technicien_tarificationtache', 
 'tarificationtache_id','technicien_id');

}
public function intervention() {
    return $this->hasMany(intervention::class);
}
```

this is my actual interface

[image]

this is the interface to done 
[image]

Comment: seriously this solution is present all over the stackoverflow , if you have any particulat error then share, or check for undefined error in Ajax

Comment: Moreover, You've shared everything except your Ajax code where the problem lies most probably

Comment: @BILALMALIK 
I do not find how I'm going to do it